# Ember model fields with number don’t get underscored properly

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-data

I have some fields in my `order` model: `address1` and `address2`. They need to be sent to my API as `address_1` and `address_2`.

When I run `Ember.String.underscore` inside of `keyForAttribute` I get:

```
Ember.String.underscore('address1')
"address1"
```

Any ideas how I can explicitly tell Ember what to do with these?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do this using a custom serializer

```
// app/serializers/application.js

export default DS.RESTSerializer.extend({
  keyForAttribute: function(key) {
    // From http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.String.html#method_underscore
    return Ember.String.underscore(key);
  }
});
```

https://discuss.emberjs.com/t/underscore-model-name-in-json-while-saving-model/8913/2

Comment: `Ember.String.underscore('address1')` is returning the result `address1` not the address_1. . to make it possible he has to find appropriate function or util

Comment: Any ideas what the solution is here? Do I need to provide more info to the question?